# Common resolution of singularities

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are varieties over a field $K$ of characteristic $0$.
If $X$ and $Y$ are birational, in the sense that there exist open dense $U\subset X$ and $V\subset Y$ which are isomorphic, can we then find a smooth variety $Z$ and maps $Z\rightarrow X$ and $Z\rightarrow Y$ which are resolutions of singularities? I think this should be a) true and b) well-known in the literature, but it seems like I cannot find a reference. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with a birational map $f$ from $X$ to $Y$. Let $Z$ be the closure of $f$ in $X\times Y$. Take $W$ to be a resolution of $Z$. This has all the properties you require.